# Make interval list between two date in vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to make a list look like below to insert into a table between two date range:

```
make_intervals_list ('2016-01-01','2020-12-31');
+----------------+--------------+--------+
| interval_start | interval_end |  rate  |
+----------------+--------------+--------+
| 2016-01-01     | 2016-12-31   |   95   |
| 2017-01-01     | 2017-12-31   |  105   | 
| 2018-01-01     | 2018-12-31   |  115   |
| 2019-01-01     | 2019-12-31   |  125   |
| 2020-01-01     | 2020-12-31   |  135   |
+----------------+--------------+--------+
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
Dim stDate As Date
Dim nxDate As Date
Dim enDate As Date
Dim rate As Integer

stDate = "01/01/2016"
enDate = "31/12/2020"
rate = Me.initial_rate

Do While stDate < enDate
    nxDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, stDate)
    stDate = nxDate
    rate = rate + 10
    Debug.Print stDate, nxDate, rate
Loop
```

Output:

```
01/01/2018    01/01/2018     115 
01/01/2019    01/01/2019     125 
01/01/2020    01/01/2020     135 
01/01/2021    01/01/2021     145
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  You needed two extra temp dates to help you through the loop:

```
Dim stDate As Date
Dim nxstDate As Date
Dim nxenDate As Date
Dim nxyrDate As Date
Dim enDate As Date
Dim rate As Integer

stDate = "01/01/2016"
enDate = "31/12/2020"
rate = Me.initial_rate

nxyrDate = stDate
Do While nxyrDate < enDate
    nxstDate = nxyrDate
    nxyrDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, nxstDate)
    nxenDate = DateAdd("d", -1, nxyrDate)
    Debug.Print nxstDate, nxenDate, rate
    rate = rate + 10
Loop
```

Output:

> ```
> 1/1/2016      12/31/2016     95 
> 1/1/2017      12/31/2017     105 
> 1/1/2018      12/31/2018     115 
> 1/1/2019      12/31/2019     125 
> 1/1/2020      12/31/2020     135
> ```

Hope that helps :)

** *EDIT* **

Additional code to answer request for placing results into a table:

First you need to create the table in your Access database

I called my table: `tblIntervals_List`

But you can call yours whatever you want, just change `tblIntervals_List` to your table name in the code below.

In Table `tblIntervals_List` you need three fields.  You can name the fields whatever you want.  But the first two fields must be of data type `Date/Time` and the third of data type `Number`.

Such as:

```
tblIntervals_List 

Field Name           Data Type

Interval_Start       Date/Time 
Interval_End         Date/Time 
Rate                 Number
```

Once you have created your table correctly, you can modify your code.

First You'll need to add another Dim statement for your SQL Insert Text:

```
Dim strSQLText As String
```

Then you'll need to turn off Warnings so you don't have to press the space bar after each record insert.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
```

Then in your loop, you need to create your SQL Insert code:

```
strSQLText = "INSERT INTO tblIntervals_List VALUES ('" & _
             nxstDate & "', '" & _
             nxenDate & "', " & _
             rate & ") "
```

And run it with a `Docmd` statement:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLText
```

Then after the loop is finished, you need to reset your warnings on:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)
```

And if you want, give your user a message box to let them know the query actually did something:

```
MsgBox "Records added to tblIntervals_List"
```

Plus, don't forget to comment out your `Debug.Print`

All of these steps are in the code below:

```
Dim stDate As Date
Dim nxstDate As Date
Dim nxenDate As Date
Dim nxyrDate As Date
Dim enDate As Date
Dim rate As Integer

Dim strSQLText As String

DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)

stDate = "01/01/2016"
enDate = "31/12/2020"
rate = Me.initial_rate

nxyrDate = stDate
Do While nxyrDate < enDate
    nxstDate = nxyrDate
    nxyrDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, nxstDate)
    nxenDate = DateAdd("d", -1, nxyrDate)
'    Debug.Print nxstDate, nxenDate, rate

    strSQLText = "INSERT INTO tblIntervals_List VALUES ('" & _
                 nxstDate & "', '" & _
                 nxenDate & "', " & _
                 rate & ") "
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQLText

    rate = rate + 10
Loop

DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)
MsgBox "Records added to tblIntervals_List"
```

And that code will add records to your Access table with your dates and rates.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes, It's perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: could you please help to insert this recordset into table

Comment: @Mir Abzal Ali:  I edited the above answer to show you how to launch SQL code that will insert records to a table. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do to make it easy for you to print out:

```
Dim stDate As Date
Dim nxDate As Date
Dim enDate As Date
Dim rate As Integer
Dim array_var As Variant

' additional variables
Dim coll_temp As Collection
Set coll_temp = New Collection
Dim array_temp(2) As Variant

' initialize initial variables
stDate = "01/01/2016"
nxDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, stDate)
nxDate = DateAdd("d", -1, nxDate)
enDate = "31/12/2020"
rate = 95 ' for you this would be Me.initial_rate

Do While stDate < enDate
    ' load array
    array_temp(0) = stDate
    array_temp(1) = nxDate
    array_temp(2) = rate

    ' add to collection
    coll_temp.Add Item:=array_temp

    ' increment dates
    nxDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, nxDate)
    stDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, stDate)
    rate = rate + 10
Loop
```

To read this out this is the loop you need to do.

```
' print out each element in collection
For Each array_var In coll_temp
    ' print out each element in array
    For int_element = 0 To UBound(array_temp)
        ' print the element
        Debug.Print array_var(0); array_var(1); array_var(2)
    Next int_element
Next
```

I hope this helps.